# fprint doesn't find my laptop's fingerprint device but lsusb does?

Tags: debian, security, drivers, fingerprint

So when i use lsusb i can find the fingerprint device, the name of it is Generic goodix fingerprint device and my laptop is lenovo thinkpad 530s

considering that lsusb can find it then why can't fprint find it? i just want to use this fingerprint for login authentication, i am using parrot security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the USB standards, there is a well-defined way to get Vendor ID and Product ID numbers from any USB device. `lsusb` just looks them up in a big table and displays the human-readable texts associated with those entries. The table is typically located at `/usr/share/misc/usb.ids` or `/var/lib/usbutils/usb.ids`.

`fprint` has a much more complicated task: since there doesn't seem to be standard USB protocols for fingerprint readers, it must know exactly what model-specific messages to send to the  reader and how to interpret the answers it gets. So it only looks for devices it knows how to talk to.

Unfortunately, it looks like the Goodix fingerprint device is not at all related to devices currently supported by `fprint`, and uses a different protocol. But looks like [Antonio Ospite is in the process of analyzing the protocol](https://gitlab.collabora.com/ao2/goodix_fp_dump) of at least some Goodix fingerprint reader(s). You might also check [this Github page](https://github.com/IDerr/Goodix92) and the links mentioned on it for similar reverse-engineering efforts.

If you're at all familiar with programming, you might try compiling Antonio's test program from the GitLab page linked above, and seeing if it works with your fingerprint reader. You could also contact the developer of that program and offer your help - at the very least, you could test Antonio's new versions with your hardware and capture USB traffic for comparative analysis. Perhaps by working together with Antonio (and maybe others that may have done the same) you might figure out the protocol so that `fprint` support can then be implemented.

Comment: So what should i do? i googled the specific name (that generic thing) and couldn't find anything related to this

Comment: @MeryTed I updated my answer, now that I'm no longer mobile-posting and can do some real Googling.

Comment: So the reason for this problem is that the developers at lenovo or whoever made that fingerprinting device didn't provide a linux support/driver? will i still have a chance at using it if i install ubuntu and not use parrot? (if it does help should i download version 18 or 19? )

Comment: Goodix does not seem to provide neither a driver nor programming documentation for the fingerprint device. If there is no Linux driver (as the situation seems to be), then changing to another Linux distribution is unlikely to help.